# convert df from factor to numeric

Tags: r, encode, sapply, datamatrix

I am struggling to convert my dataset into numeric values. The dataset I have looks like this:

```
customer_id 2012 2013 2013 2014  2015 2016 2017
15251        X     N     U    D     S    C    L
```

X1 - X7 are marked as factors. The extract from dput(head(df)) is:

```
    structure(list(`2012` = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("N", 
"X"), class = "factor"), `2013` = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L
), .Label = c("C", "D", "N", "S", "U", "X"), class = "factor"), 
    `2014` = structure(c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("C", 
    "D", "L", "N", "R", "S", "U", "X"), class = "factor"), ...
```

I would like to have the data in numeric values, but I don't know how I can transform them accordingly. 
The goal is that I can feed the df into a heatmap so that I can visually explore the differences. To my knowledge, this is only possible with a numeric matrix. Because I get the error *Heatmap.2(input, trace = "none", : `x' must be a numeric matrix*

Does someone have any idea?

Many Thanks for your support!

Comment: Hi Lebowski I have suggested something below. My suggestion is next time, ask the question in a more direct way, for example, how to visualize a matrix of letters.. Maybe that will get you less down votes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's do-able. I think it would help next time to include the complete df. The heatmap.2 does not work because you gave it a character matrix. It's a bit more complicated to display the legend for color to letters using heatmap.2, I suggest something below using ggplot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(viridis)

# simulate data
df = data.frame(id=1:5,
replicate(7,sample(LETTERS[1:10],5)))
colnames(df)[-1] = 2012:2018

#convert to long format for plotting and refactor
df <- df %>% pivot_longer(-id) %>%
mutate(value=factor(as.character(value),levels=sort(levels(value))))

#define color scale
# sorted in alphabetical order
present_letters = levels(df$value)
COLS = viridis_pal()(length(present_letters))
names(COLS) = present_letters

#plot
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=name,y=id,fill=value)) + 
geom_tile() + 
scale_fill_manual(values=COLS)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi StupidWolf. That's great advice! Thank you very much for your solution. Do you know by any chance how I can include the dendrogram? (to somehow sort them in cluster order)?

Comment: Hey @Lebowski, how would you like to cluster? I mean what you have are letters.. unless there's a defined way to convert them to numeric..

Comment: Hi StupidWolf. I encoded them into numeric values, and gave them numbers from 1-8 but are not entierly sure if this is correct. What I was thinking to try is using the package stringdist and sequence analysis (BioMedR and msa)...

Comment: @Lebowski you have amino acids? Yeah you need to align to get the order first. Putting a heatmap together with a dendrogram is not so easy with ggplot2. You can try heatmap.2 or pheatmap. But hey, do you need to do this alot? If it is once, I would combine them using illustrator lol

Comment: You can also try asking your question (please provide data and code !) at https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ , someone might have a good solution

Comment: Hi StupidWolf. Yeah, it was kinda tricky to have nice dendrograms with a heatmap but now I got the trick...but only by converting the characters into numbers. 
No, the data are actually just Strings of a customer behaviour over time. I created the characters myself. My Professor thought it would be great if I could use the analogy of bioinformatics to extract some "hidden" patterns. Have a good day.